# SQLite:java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

Before i post my question,i tried all solutions but i can not resolve my problem.Can any one help me to find the solution ?

I m trying to get data from table "Email" but each time it  invokes this exception

> java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY     at
>   org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4ResultSet.first(JDBC4ResultSet.java:402)    at
>   HMDao.EmailDao.FindString(EmailDao.java:144)  at
>   hmproject.StartingController.initialize(StartingController.java:103)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)     at
>   hmproject.HMProject.start(HMProject.java:34)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)

This is my code :

```
 public Email FindString(String ID) {

        Email email = null;

        String querySelectEmployer = "SElECT Email,Password FROM Email";

        try {

            ResultSet resultSet = Dbaconnection.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY).executeQuery(querySelectEmployer);


            if (resultSet.first()) {

                email = new Email(resultSet.getString("Email"), resultSet.getString("Password"));
            }
            resultSet.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return email;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `first()` refers to an "absolute position" within the data set, which is available only for cursor result sets.

Since you do not need repositioning, only moving the cursor to the initial record, replacing the call of `first()` with `next()` will do the trick:

```
if (resultSet.next()) {
    email = new Email(resultSet.getString("Email"), resultSet.getString("Password"));
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer @dasblinkenlight , but about my password ,i developed an algorithm can encrypt password but i save it like a string in my database,because i have not a feedback about security of application.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Even if you encrypt password it is still dangerous. If you use your own encryption scheme, it is likely that it could be broken. Even if you use a proven strong encryption algorithm with a strong key, the key becomes the weak point of the system: if this key is stolen, it becomes possible to decrypt all passwords.

Comment: I think,i will use MD5 to encrypt my password,thanks for your advice.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine Please do not use MD5, use a proven password hash like PBKDF2, bcrypt, etc.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I m using Jasypt.

Comment: Jasypt is not a hashing algorithm, it is a library.